# NameError Uninitialized constant for a has_many association after upgrading to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I try to upgrade my rails app to 4.0.1 and i get an Error in my controller for the line @gallery.pictures.build:

```
NameError in GalleriesController#new
uninitialized constant Gallery::Picture

  @gallery = Gallery.new
  @gallery.token = @gallery.generate_token
  @picture = @gallery.pictures.build
  @pictures = []
```

I haven't changed any code except of using strong parameters and can't figure out the reason why the code broke. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Here's more code if it helps finding the error:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /galleries
  # GET /galleries.json
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @galleries }
    end
  end

  # GET /galleries/1
  # GET /galleries/1.json
  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @picture = @gallery.pictures.build
    @pictures = Picture.find(:all, :conditions  => [ 'gallery_id = ?', @gallery.id ])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @gallery }
    end
  end

  # GET /galleries/new
  # GET /galleries/new.json
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
    @gallery.token = @gallery.generate_token
    @picture = @gallery.pictures.build
    @pictures = []

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @gallery }
    end
  end

  # GET /galleries/1/edit
  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @picture = @gallery.pictures.build
    @pictures = []
  end

  # POST /galleries
  # POST /galleries.json
  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
    @pictures = Picture.where(:gallery_token => @gallery.token)
    @gallery.pictures << @pictures

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.save
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /galleries/1
  # PUT /galleries/1.json
  def update
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update_attributes(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /galleries/1
  # DELETE /galleries/1.json
  def destroy
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @gallery.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to galleries_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
     def set_gallery
        @project = @label.projects.find(params[:id])
     end

    # Use this method to whitelist the permissible parameters. Example:
    #   params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    #
    # Also, you can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible
    # attributes.
    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:cover, :description, :name, :token)
    end

end
```

class PicturesController < ApplicationController

```
  before_action :set_picture, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /pictures
  # GET /pictures.json
  def index

    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])

    @pictures = @gallery.pictures

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pictures }
    end
  end

  # GET /pictures/1
  # GET /pictures/1.json
  def show
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @picture }
    end
  end

  # GET /pictures/new
  # GET /pictures/new.json
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
    @picture = @gallery.pictures.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @picture }
    end
  end

  # GET /pictures/1/edit
  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])

    @picture = @gallery.pictures.find(params[:id])
    # @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pictures
  # POST /pictures.json
  def create
    p_attr = params[:picture]
    Rails.logger.debug("[debug] : #{p_attr}" );
    p_attr[:image] = params[:picture][:image].first if params[:picture][:image].class == Array
    Rails.logger.debug("[debug] : #{p_attr[:image]}" );

    if params[:gallery_id]
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
      @picture = @gallery.pictures.build(p_attr)
    else
      @picture = Picture.new(p_attr)
    end

    if @picture.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          render :json => [@picture.to_jq_upload].to_json,
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }
        format.json {
          render :json => [@picture.to_jq_upload].to_json
        }
      end
    else
      render :json => [{:error => "custom_failure"}], :status => 304
    end
  end

  # PUT /pictures/1
  # PUT /pictures/1.json
  def update

    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])

    @picture = @gallery.pictures.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
        format.html { redirect_to gallery_path(@gallery), notice: 'Picture was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pictures/1
  # DELETE /pictures/1.json
  def destroy
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
    @picture = @gallery.pictures.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to gallery_pictures_url }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def make_default
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])

    @gallery.cover = @picture.id
    @gallery.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
     def set_picture
        @project = @label.projects.find(params[:id])
     end

    # Use this method to whitelist the permissible parameters. Example:
    #   params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    #
    # Also, you can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible
    # attributes.
    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:description, :gallery_id, :image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :gallery_token)
    end
end
```

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

```
      has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy

      def generate_token
        self.token = loop do
          random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
          break random_token unless Gallery.where(token: random_token).exists?
        end
      end

    end
```

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

```
  belongs_to :gallery

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  after_update :crop_image

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:image),
      "size" => image.size,
      "url" => image.url,
      "thumbnail_url" => image.thumb.url,
      "delete_url" => id,
      "picture_id" => id,
      "delete_type" => "DELETE"
    }
  end

  def crop_image
    image.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
    current_version = self.image.current_path
    large_version = "#{Rails.root}/public" + self.image.versions[:large].to_s

    FileUtils.rm(current_version)
    FileUtils.cp(large_version, current_version)
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens when you do Gallery.new.pictures.build in the rails console?

Comment: Thank you for making me debug with the console! Turned out to be a problem with the deprecated "include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper" in the uploader class used for the picture-model.
Thank you for your effort and i'm very sorry for being such a noob...